# Custom annotations in Java comprising other annotaitons

Tags: java, spring, rest, annotations, jersey-2.0

I am writing REST services in Java and almost all the Rest resource serving methods have below given list of annotations and all these annotations are default required for many methods.

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/XYZ")
public String getXYZ(String jsonRequest) {
}
```

So I want to create my custom annotations like this

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyRest {

POST post() default @POST();
Path path();
Produces produces() default @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
Consumes consumes() default @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
}
```

And thus I have to apply only one annotation for many methods

```
 @MyRest(path = @Path("/XYZ"))
 public RestServiceResponse getXYZ(String jsonRequest)
```

I tried the above code but then Jersey is not able to resolve the path and throws exception HTTP error code 405 , method not supported.
So my question is , is not the above code correct ? Should not Jersey understand my custome annotation ?

Comment: If you have ever used reflection to get annotations, you will understand why this does not work. Jersey finds the `Method` through reflection, and looks for a `@Path` annotation on the `Method`. It doesn't look for a `@MyRest` annotation.

Comment: Thank you. So every method need to have same bunch of annotations ? If you know any simpler way to get this done ?

Comment: Simple, no.  However, if you are determined you can use [Jersey's programmatic API](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/resource-builder.html) to offer support for your own annotations.

Comment: You can put `@Produces` and `@Consumes` on the class level. It will trickle down to all methods. You can override it at the method level by simply adding a different annotation.